# How to follow button clicks with node request?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to follow an input button (one of those buttons on a timer saying "Proceed to this page") using my node application. I am using request.js to scrape the page for information and all of the information is past the button. I understand this may be impossible for security reasons, but I was hoping someone here knows of a solution as I have been unable to find one for the last couple days. Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying you want to be able to click the link and scrape the page that follows it?

Comment: @JustinHathaway Essentially yes, but it's not a normal anchor link, it is a form submit button that runs a server-side auth script and serves the page's content. The page reloads when this happens.